# Baixa resoluçao IONIC CAMERA

Tags: typescript, ionic, mobile, ionic4

Estou tendo um problema com a resolução das fotos no meu aplicativo.
Meu aquivo TS. esta com as seguinte configurão:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PictureSourceType, Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ActionSheetController } from '@ionic/angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pic-register',
  templateUrl: './pic-register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pic-register.page.scss'],
})

export class PicRegisterPage implements OnInit {

   public photo: string;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private camera: Camera,
    private ActionSheetController: ActionSheetController

  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  updateStoredImage(image) {

  }

  documentFront(){
    console.log('aqui');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/register/document-front')
  }


  async selectImage() {


    const actionSheet = await this.ActionSheetController.create({
      header: 'Selecione uma image',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Galeria',
        icon: 'file-tray-full-outline',
        handler: () => {
          this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Camera',
        icon: 'camera',
        handler: () => {
          this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA)
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Cancelar',
        role: 'cancel',
        icon: 'log-out-outline',
      }]
    });
    await actionSheet.present();

  }

  takePicture(sourceType: PictureSourceType) {

    this.photo = '';

    var options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: sourceType,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation: true,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then(imageData => {
      let base64image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.photo = base64image;
    }, error =>{
      console.log(error);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

}
```

Ocorre o upload normal da foto porem a mesma é renderizada da seguinte forma com a qualidade muito baixa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem saberia qual erro esta correndo uma vez que na opções da camera que coloquei a qualidade para 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olhando a [documentação](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/camera/#CameraOptions), você verá que `targetWidth` e `targetHeight` possuem os valores especificados em **pixels**. No seu código:

```
var options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: sourceType,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation: true,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      targetWidth: 100, // 100px
      targetHeight: 100 // 100px
}
```

Isso faz com que a foto tirada seja redimensionada ao ser exibida, "perdendo qualidade". Altere os valores para uma proporção que seja possível realizar o que você precisa.

Comment: Eu tentei com 400x400 porem não renderizou nenhuma imagem. Acredito que se eu suprimir essas duas variáveis ele pegara o padrão enviado pela câmera, correto?

Comment: Na documentação não é citado o valor padrão, então presumo que sim. Se você não especificar os valores, a imagem aparece?

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Quando não seta as os valores ele pega a qualidade total da imagem.